# Transfer changed/Added data on some tables from one instance to another instance?

Tags: sql-server

How can we transfer changed/Added data on **some** tables from one instance to another instance?

Comment: replication springs to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **INSERTED, UPDATE(COLUMN_NAME)** to achieve the results.

Also use **linked server queries** since you want to copy data from one instance to another